# Pygame datetime troubles

Tags: python, datetime, time, pygame

I was experimenting with some datetime code in python so I could do a time.sleep like function on one piece of code, while letting other code run.
Here is my code:

```
import datetime, pygame

pygame.init()
secondtick = pygame.time.Clock()

timestr = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())

timelist = list(timestr)

timex = 1
while timex <= 6:
    timelist.pop(0)
    timex += 1
timex2 = 1

while timex2 <= 7:
    timelist.pop(2)
    timex2 += 1
secondstr1 = str("".join(timelist))

while 1:
    timestr = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())

    timelist = list(timestr)

    timex = 1
    while timex <= 6:
        timelist.pop(0)
        timex += 1
    timex2 = 1
    while timex2 <= 7:
        timelist.pop(2)
        timex2 += 1

    secondstr2 = str("".join(timelist))

    x = 1

    if int(secondstr2) - x == int(secondstr1):
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

and here is the result:

```
C:\Python32\python.exe "C:/Users/depia/PycharmProjects/testing/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/depia/PycharmProjects/testing/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    timelist.pop(2)
IndexError: pop index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I add a time.sleep(1) after importing time right here:

```
    -- code --
    time.sleep(1)
    secondstr2 = str("".join(timelist))
    -- more code --
```

this is the output:

```
C:\Python32\python.exe "C:/Users/depia/PycharmProjects/testing/test.py"
1
```

then it never ends. It just stays like that forever. Can anyone help?

Comment: what do you try to do ? Maybe learn how to use `pygame.time` and work without `time.sleep`

Comment: I was trying to make it so that one part would wait, but the rest can run. Ex. One animation waits a second before it plays again, but the player can still move around while it is playing. The whole part with all the while loops was to isolate the seconds in the time. I've looked at pygame.time, and I can't seem to see anything other than pygame.time.delay(), which will pause the whole thing.

Comment: you can use `pygame.time.get_ticks` but in different way. To delay 1 second (1000ms) first you set `end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1000` and later in loop you check `if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= end_time: do_something()`

Comment: or you can use `pygame.time.set_timer()` to create own event every 1000ms. First set `pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1 , 1000)` and later in loop you check `for event ...: if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1: do_something()`

Comment: Thank you SO much! Can you set this as an answer so I can select it and other people can see it quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pygame.time.get_ticks](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to control time.

To delay your event for 1 second (1000ms) first you set

```
end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1000
```

and later in loop you check

```
if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= end_time: 
    do_something()
```

or even (to repeat it every 1000ms)

```
if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= end_time: 
    do_something() 
    end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1000 
    #end_time = end_time + 1000
```

It is very popular method to control times for many different elements in the same loop.

---

Or you can use [pygame.time.set_timer()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to create own event every 1000ms.

First set

```
 pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 1000)
```

and later in loop you check

```
 for event in pygame.event.get(): 
     if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1: 
          do_something()
```

It is useful if you have to do something periodicaly

BTW: use `0` to turn off event

```
 pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+1, 0)
```